# c code for converting a 1d data into 3d in c

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array in 1D.

```
data[27]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27};
```

I need to convert this into a 3D array of the form using C:

```
data[3][3][3]
```

Can someone help me doing this?

---

I tried the following code. Not seems to be working:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{    
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int res;
    int data;
    int byte[] data={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27}; // Read 4096 bytes
    byte[][][] res = new byte[3][3][3];
    for (x = 0 ; x != 3 ; x++) {
        for (y = 0 ; y != 3 ; y++) {
            for (z = 0 ; z != 3 ; z++) {
                res[x][y][z] = data[3*3*x + 3*y + z];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Printing the 3D matrix\n");
    for (x = 0 ; x != 16 ; x++) {
        for (y = 0 ; y != 16 ; y++) {
            for (z = 0 ; z != 16 ; z++) {
                printf("%d\t",res[x][y][z]);
                printf("\n");
            } 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not C code. And please describe your problem better than "doesn't work". What exactly is the behaviour? And have you used a debugger to step thru the code to try and find out what you may be doing wrong?

Comment: `byte[][][] res = new byte[3][3][3];` should not compile. It looks like Java, not C or C++. Can you show your compile and link command? Or show the error from trying to compile and link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic seems to be okay. The problem is with the declaration of the 1D and 3D arrays.

1) There id no datatype as `byte` in C

2) `new` is not a part of C. You cannot allocate memory using `new`

Try the following changes for your code to work

```
int main()
{

int x;
int y;
int z;
int data[] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27}; // Read 4096 bytes
int res[3][3][3];
for (x = 0 ; x < 3 ; x++) {
    for (y = 0 ; y < 3 ; y++) {
        for (z = 0 ; z < 3 ; z++) {
            res[x][y][z] = data[3*3*x + 3*y + z];
        }
    }
}
printf("Printing the 3D matrix\n");
//run the loop till maximum value of x, y & z
for (x = 0 ; x < 3 ; x++) {
    for (y = 0 ; y < 3 ; y++) {
        for (z = 0 ; z < 3 ; z++) {
            printf("%d\t",res[x][y][z]);
            printf("\n");
        } 
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I hope you understood the modifications

Comment: Yeah i understood. Thanks again.

Comment: If i can ask you one more thing. How do i increase the stack size in Dev-c++ 5.11 ?. Because i need to process a file which is close to 30MB and i have stored it as a 1D array..any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by stack size. Do you mean stack segment of memory?